# Move a folder to another repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, springloops

I have an SVN repository structured like the following:

ROOT

- CODE
- DATA
- WEB

However it seems my WEB folder is a separate repository from the rest of the structure, meaning it has it's own .svn folder under it (WEB/.svn), and when I check in the ROOT folder, it does not include the WEB folder.

I would like to move that .svn folder from under WEB and put it under ROOT (or merge it with the one under there now), or somehow join that WEB folder into the ROOT repository so that when i check in, i can check in everything at once instead of having to do 2 checkins every time.

Is there a way to do this without losing the checkin history of the WEB folder?

I'm using Tortoise SVN 1.7.10 on Windows for my client (the upgrade to 1.7 is what caused this stuffup in the first place)

I'm using Springloops (www.slsapp.com) for my server. Not sure how much access i have to run commands on there - anybody know?

Comment: SVN before version 1.7 had a .svn directory in **every** subdirectory of the project. Maybe you need to upgrade the working copy.

Comment: That's what i did originally, but for some reason i couldn't do the whole trunk at once, so i did individual folders, which is what has caused this problem.  I'm trying to checkout the whole trunk now, hopefully that solves the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**: don't mix into jumble Repository and Working Copy. `/.svn` dir is attribute of Working Copy, which you can get from **any subtree** of tree in Repository. BTW, **real** URLs and paths in question will help to debug troubles easier

OK, I'll try to be sensitive some time and reconstruct sutuation. Fix my assumptions, if they will be wrong somewhere-somehow

- You have repository with dirs (under root directly, not trunk?) /code + /data + /web
- You checkout your WC from `URL/web` path
- Now you want to get your WC linked to `URL`

If all above is correct you have two ways

- a) Commit local changes from current WC b) Checkout into new location new Working Copy from / c) Delete old WC and use new WC
- You can *try* (no warranties, I'm too lazy to test) switch current WC to the new point of mount inside Repository: `svn switch ^/` and update your WC (`svn up`) after switch in order to get full updated tree from repository

First way is faster, simpler and less troublesome

Comment: I just did a full checkout of the trunk and it solved my problem.  So easy, thanks for the suggestion :)